# How to compare ANOVA results from multiple data sets

Tags: anova, meta-analysis, post-hoc, meta-regression, systematic-review

I am trying to find out if there is an age-education category difference between people in the number of votes which they use while voting with a multiple vote voting method.
Basically, I am trying to find out if there is a difference between a number of votes used by e.g. high-educated older people and low-educated middle-aged people.

I have 9 ANOVAs each from a different dataset from a different year and/or type of election.

The first question is probably the most important one and it is a bit theoretical:
The number of votes among the age-education groups varies depending on the context of the individual election. Usually the older people and less educated tend to use less votes but it is not a rule and sometimes goes vice versa. Depending on this fact, should I even compare these datasets? Should I approach this problem by wanting to make the general statement that age and education affect the number of votes cast, when this matter is obviously more situational? But let's say yes, I want to know in what proportion and how often voters differ in this respect, regardless of the type and specifics of the choice.

If I still want to compare all these data (groups from different years and elections), what is the best approach methodologically?

Should I make one general dataset and control for the year and type of election somehow? Is it possible to do it with an ANOVA test unless I do not want to split them into subcategories (and end up with the same 9 ANOVAs)?

Or is there a way to take these 9 ANOVAs and compare them in some kind of a meta-analysis where I compare each category with each category and find an average value while controlling for the size of each datasets etc? I only managed to find ways how to do a single ANOVA for comparing means across different datasets (in SPSS 28 for example) but not any statistically correct way to compare results of multiple ANOVAs measuring the same thing repeatedly. Should I keep those 9 ANOVAs separately and create a new dataset and make some post-hoc tests for example? In that case, which post-hoc tests would you use?

Thank you for any kind of tip or help!